# How do I retrieve the first object in an array of arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of arrays, and I want to get the first object of each array, but it is just picking up the first array and applying that to all the cells. How do I get it to take the first object of each array?

```
let animals: [[String]] = []
//animals prints ([ ["dog", "cat"], ["sheep", "bat"] ])
cell.info.text = "\(animals[0])"
//the UILabel for each cell is "dog, cat" instead I want the first cell to be "dog" and the second cell to be "sheep"
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a tableview and want to populate the `cell.info` with the first object of the arrays in `animals`?

Comment: @Eendje yes I want to populate the cell.info with the first object of each array. i.e. first object of first array goes to the first cell second object of second array goes to the second cell etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a table view and have the `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:)` return the count of `animals`:

```
let animals = [["dog", "cat"], ["sheep", "bat"]]
cell.info.text = animals[indexPath.row].first ?? "No animal available"
```

Not on my computer, so maybe I made a little mistake here and there.

Devster101 was so kind to add a screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvJ1.png)

Comment: I need more code to know what you're exactly doing. This answer is just based on my assumptions.

Comment: I don't know why your autocompletion doesn't complete `.first` because as I can tell, your array `animals` is a swift array and it should have `.first`.

Answer (score -1):

```
cell.info.text = "\(animal[0][0])"
```

That would get you to have the first cell being dog.

Comment: http://puu.sh/mJZSr/190c7cc4be.png I tried doing it like `cell.info.text = "\(animal[indexPath.item][0])"`, but I get the error

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSLog("%@", "\(animals[indexPath.row][indexPath.row])")
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can get first array first object, second array second object and so on in `animals` array.

Comment: His first cell will show the first of his array, and the second cell will show the second and so on.

Answer (score -2):

```
let animals: [[String]] = []...... replace this line with belo
let animals = [AnyObject]()
let animalName = animals[0].objectAtIndex(0) as? String
cell.info.text = animalName
```